# Dynamically apply CSS3 attributes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a for loop which works fine:

```
<div id="page1div"></div>
<script>

list = " ";

for (var i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
{
    list = "<h1 class='entriesdisplayed'>" + 
               item(i) + 
               "<span class='bolditalic'> x " + 
                   description(i) + 
               " </span>" +
           "</h1>" +
           list;
}

$("#page1div").html(list);

</script>
```

The above does show me elements of the array very accurately but I simply want to make `description(i)` appear in bold and italic.  As you see, `description(i)` is enclosed in `span class="bolditalic"`.

In my CSS3 file I have this:

```
.bolditalic
{
    font: bold italic;
}
```

Comment: This has to be the worst code I've seen this month...

Comment: @Shomz Well then you can give me a better version.

Comment: Here you go, it's more readable now and has no errors.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome tells me that `bold italic` is an invalid property value for `font`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font.

I suggest you use

```
.bolditalic
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/58ms70a6/